# Using .format() in Python, can I conditionally use .capitalize() as well?

Tags: python, python-2.7, renpy

Okay, so that might be a bit cryptic.

I have a list of food, which I randomly select items from. I use this in another list to talk about the selected food, but those strings can have the food-name both at the beginning of the sentence, and the end of the sentence.

Example:

```
default breakfast_food_list = ['pancakes','bacon and eggs','scones','sandwiches','beans and bacon','quiche','cereal','muffins']

default breakfast_nice_list = [
            ['I love your {0}',2,'fm_rel'],
            ['Ah, I just love those {0}',2,'fm_rel'],
            ['{0} is fine',1,'fm_rel'],
]

$ breakfast_select = random.randint(0,len(breakfast_food_list)-1)
$ breakfast_nice = breakfast_nice_list[breakfast_nice_select][0]
```

I'm displaying these like this:

```
$ breakfast_reply = breakfast_nice.format(breakfast_food)
```

Now, I could just slap .captialize() on the end there, but that will make it capitalized even when it's at the end or middle of the sentence.

So, I'm looking for a solution where it gets capitalized when it's the first word in the sentence and only the first word...

Comment: Why not just add the line `breakfast_reply[0].upper()`

Comment: Might I also suggest a simplification by using `from random import choice` to get a random element from a list? [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)

Comment: I meant `breakfast_reply = breakfast_reply[0].upper()`, and good suggestion Thomas Fauskanger.

Comment: Just use `.title()` after the substitutions, e.g. `breakfast_nice.format(breakfast_food).title()`

Comment: That would capitalize all the words, but I thought the goal was to only capitalize the first word if it's the food?

Comment: Or simply `breakfast_reply = breakfast_nice.format(breakfast_food).capitalize()`, I'm not sure if I'm missing a requirement there

Comment: Ah, of course, yes that would be the simpler solution

Comment: Yes sorry, got my call mixed up, meant `.capitalize()`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I've updated answer from input in comments on the question (and this answer). **//EDIT**

You could try something like this:

```
from random import choice

default breakfast_food_list = ['pancakes','bacon and 
     eggs','scones','sandwiches','beans and bacon','quiche','cereal','muffins']

default breakfast_nice_list = [
    ['I love your {0}',2,'fm_rel'],
    ['Ah, I just love those {0}',2,'fm_rel'],
    ['{0} is fine',1,'fm_rel']]

words = choice(breakfast_nice_list)[0]
food = choice(breakfast_food_list)
output = words.format(food).capitalize()
```

Comment: While slightly less efficient but perhaps more readable, just call `.capitalize()` after the format, e.g. `output = words.format(food).capitalize()`

Comment: That there is of course the right answer... I blame my utter complete tiredness for making this way more complicated than it actually was. Adding `.capitalize()` after is of course exactly what's needed.

Answer (score -2):

If you're on Python3.6, you might be able to do some rearranging and use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals). Like

`breakfast_choice = breakfast_food_list[breakfast_select]`

`breakfast_reply = f"{breakfast_choice.capitalize()} is fine"`

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I was not aware of this, and I am primarily on 3.6. The question, however, is tagged with Python2.7 :P